# Animate the squares

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to move button like this in the link http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/game/twincol/ but i cant move it. using css animation i can move in a straight forward animation. is it possible to move off the screen and come in the screen and a particlular movement and direction to a box like the link.here is what i have done.

```
<div id="box" style='width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;'/>

    <button id="one" type="button" >Button1</button>
    <button id="two" type="button" >Button2</button>
<button id="three" type="button">Button3</button>

<style>

button{
-webkit-appearance:none;width:40px;height:40px;padding: 0;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;border: 1px solid red;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;
}

#one, #two, #three
{
position:relative;

}
#one
{
-webkit-animation:levelseven 16s  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;




}

#two
{

animation-direction:alternate;

/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation:levelseven_1 8s  infinite;

}

#three
{

animation-direction:alternate;

/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation:levelseven_2 10s  infinite;

}


@-webkit-keyframes levelseven /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  { left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  { left:100px; top:200px;}
75%  { left:150px; top:50px;}
100% {background:cyan; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes levelseven_1 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {background:darkgoldenrod; left:0px; top:200px;}
100% { left:0px; top:0px;}
  }


@-webkit-keyframes levelseven_2 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

</style>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcxqx/1/)

Comment: The movement of the boxes (in the link) don't have any cycle (I mean the movement/the path of a box should be the same in each cycle). In fact the movement is not repeated, it's fairly dynamic. So I think just `animation` won't help you unless more script is added.

Comment: i am not good in jscript thats the reason i used css. can anyone show how the link http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/game/twincol/ is designed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish it by CSS3 animation.That will be really really complex,cause you've got to write many keyframes codes of every single button.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcxqx/3/)

First, I let the big div's `overflow:hidden`.Just want to make an example by moving the first button.I add 50.1%，50.2% and 50.3% in keyframes.Maybe the thoughts can help you rewrite your HTML page.JS codes are recommended to realize this effect.

Comment: even complex CSS3 animation cannot do it. It's too dynamic, in fact the direction is considered to be just 45deg, but it could be any. A cycle of the movements (if exists) may contain many many movements beforehand, if you build a CSS3 animation, you may have to calculate all the movements yourself with a **fixed** input (that means a fixed location and a fixed direction **initially**).

Answer (score -1):

You can't use keyframe animations for this.

You have to use javascript. Look into using the modulo operator % to get the effect of infinite boundaries.

Also, to avoid too much complexity handling the divs, you should use canvas instead of divs.

So, go and learn JS, the Canvas API and what the % operator does - then you can solve your problem.